# Create a list dynamically of editText in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-edittext

I have an EditText for the user to write how many players will be in a game. Then I have a ScrollView with a vertical LinearLayout where I want to create as many EditTexts (for the player names) as the user gave in the first editText. How can I do that?

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: don't use a Linearlayout with scrollview, Use a RecyclerView

Comment: yep, use RecyclerView. -> link : http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple. Instead of using xml layout view you have to create it programmatically in java file.

Eg. to create an edit text you can use:

```
EditText myEditText = new EditText(context); // Pass it an Activity or Context
myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(..., ...)); // Pass two args; must be LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, or an integer pixel value.
myLayout.addView(myEditText);
```

And after that add a button which fetch No. of players (lets say 5) from edit text and hence create 5 edit text using a for loop.

Comment: this has to be the worst suggestion ever. I would use RecyclerView instead.